# Complex Search in a through model for Many to many relationships in Django

Tags: python, django, search, django-rest-framework, many-to-many

We are using Django Rest Framework to expose API's to Add, edit and retrieve data about users and their skill (with levels)

We have models for users, skills and the skillmatrix (through model where we need to add additional data about skill level of that user for a given skill.)

```
class Freelancer(models.Model):
    user = models.UUIDField (primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    contactNumber = models.BigIntegerField (default=None,blank=True, null=True)
    emailAddress = models.EmailField (max_length=50, blank=False, null=True)
    bachelorsDegree = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    mastersDegree = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    userCertificates =  models.TextField(max_length=200)    
    IsActive = models.BooleanField (default=True)
    UserPassword = models.CharField (max_length=50)
    DeacivateDate = models.DateTimeField (blank=True, null=True)
    Address = models.TextField(max_length=200)
    Pincode = models.IntegerField()

class Skill(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    skilltype = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True)
    userSkills = models.ManyToManyField(Freelancer,through='SkillMatrix')

class SkillMatrix(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(Freelancer,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    skill = models.ForeignKey(Skill,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    level = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True)
```

**Now my challenge is the following:**

I want to find the most efficient way to search for users with specific skills and return it in the order of most relevant to least relevant. There are around 10000 users and around 300 skills.

So for example if the required skills are ["python", "html", "css", "postgres"] then I should be able to return a list of UserID's so that

User1 >> Skills Python, html, css, postgres all advanced

User2 >> Skills python html, css advanced, postgres intermediate

User3>> Skills python, html, css advanced, no postgres skill

Please help!

Comment: What if one user has two advanced matches, whereas another has three intermediate? You need some sort of score to sum up expertise levels. Furthermore it might be useful to make `level` an integer then (and for example use `choices=...`) to map these on text.

Comment: Furthermore something that seems conceptually missing is that the potential employer should be able to specify a required level?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem  Interesting idea about storing level as integers. Will use that. Other than that, the fundamental question still remains,  what is a pluggable tool that I can use for this? As far as employer specifying, that's something I am forseeing in the future, but right now assume that they just list the skills.